# Hoy to get all keys (not all key+values) in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I need to have a Hyperledger Fabric chaincode method that returns all keys in my world state to perform an integrity check. I can obviously get all states with getStateByRange() and iterate just to get the keys, method but I have seen that it effectively returns all data which overloads my system (I have about 20.000 objects in my world state)

Is there a way to get just the keys in a way that does not force Fabric to fetch all world state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the [chaincode shim APIs](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim#ChaincodeStubInterface) does not support a `GetKeys()`. You should be able to use `GetStateByRangeWithPagination()` to avoid overloading your system while building your list of keys.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that method.